# Some characters in WCF REST parameter from UriTemplate are HTML encoded

Tags: c#, wcf, urlencode, html-encode, uritemplate

I have the following Web Service interface (a WCF service) method defined:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "sites/{siteId}/storage/{*filePath}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[OperationContract]
FileUploadResultDto UploadMultipart(Stream fileData, string siteId, string filePath);
```

If I do a HTTP POST request to: "(host)/sites/1234/storage/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0.html" (this is the URL-encoded version of "мама.html")

Parameter filePath is read as "&#1084;а&#1084;а.html", which is wrong.

I'd like it to be directly read as "мама.html".

However, "&#1084;" is the html-encoded version of the "м" character.

Why is WCF/UriTemplate behaving this way? How can I directly obtain a direct representation of the string, and not have some of the character html-encoded? Is there a setting in web.config for this? Is it a bug?